# How to get more results from the octokit api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api, octokit

I want to get all the repos from github using [octokit](https://github.com/octokit).

So I use  `throttling` and `paginateRest` and `restEndpointMethods` plugins.

But no matter what is my search query it's return 1020 results max.

How I can get the all results?

```
const searchQuery = "stars:>1+language:JavaScript";

import { Octokit } from "@octokit/core";
import { throttling } from "@octokit/plugin-throttling";
import { paginateRest } from "@octokit/plugin-paginate-rest";
import { restEndpointMethods } from "@octokit/plugin-rest-endpoint-methods";

(async () => {
  const MyOctokit = Octokit.plugin(
    throttling,
    paginateRest,
    restEndpointMethods
  );

  const octokit = new MyOctokit({
    auth: '..',
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/vnd.github.preview",
    },
    throttle: {
      onRateLimit: (retryAfter, options, octokit) => {
        octokit.log.warn(
          `Request quota exhausted for request ${options.method} ${options.url}`
        );

        if (options.request.retryCount === 0) {
          // only retries once
          octokit.log.info(`Retrying after ${retryAfter} seconds!`);
          return true;
        }
      },
      onAbuseLimit: (retryAfter, options, octokit) => {
        // does not retry, only logs a warning
        octokit.log.warn(
          `Abuse detected for request ${options.method} ${options.url}`
        );
      },
    },
  });

  const results = await octokit.paginate(octokit.rest.search.repos, {
    q: searchQuery,
  });

  console.log({ len: results.length }); // --> output 1020. should be much more.

})();
```

Comment: fyi you don't need to set the accept header to `application/vnd.github.preview`, it was graduated in 2013: https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-10-29-search-api-becomes-an-official-part-of-github-api-v3/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're getting 1020, but [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search) state that "the GitHub Search API provides **up to 1,000 results for each search**."

This appears to be a hard limit set by Github.